# building extension for Python 3 with Swig and distutils

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, distutils

I've built an application ("Checkyrs") in C++, and now am doing something external which will use large parts of Checkyrs but is built in Python 3. (This is all something in my free time, so it doesn't **need** to be Python 3, but that's my preference.)

To get an interface between the python and C++, I'm using SWIG and the python distutils package. I've built a dynamic library containing what I need from Checkyrs, and I've successfully built a Python extension ("checkyrsai") using the tools I mentioned. I've tested it in Python 2.7 and it works fully, all of the C++ classes and functions I need are available and function correctly.

But my preference is to work with Python 3, and while I can build the extension with Python 3 I'm unable to load it successfully:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import checkyrsai
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/Programming/eggyolk/checkyrsai.py", line 28, in <module>
    _checkyrsai = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/chris/Documents/Programming/eggyolk/checkyrsai.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_checkyrsai', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/chris/Documents/Programming/eggyolk/_checkyrsai.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN4Game11ExecuteMoveERKSt6vectorI8PositionSaIS1_EE
  Referenced from: /Users/chris/Documents/Programming/eggyolk/_checkyrsai.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/chris/Documents/Programming/eggyolk/_checkyrsai.so
```

My process for building the extension (for Python 2) is:

```
swig -c++ -python checkyrsai.i
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

where my setup.py file looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import os

os.environ["CC"] = "g++"

checkyrsai = Extension('_checkyrsai',
                    sources = ['checkyrsai_wrap.cxx','../checkyrs/checkyrs/ai.cpp'],
                    include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include','../checkyrs/checkyrs'],
                    libraries = ['Checkyrs'],
                    library_dirs = ['../checkyrs/Build/Products/Release/','/usr/local/lib'],
                    extra_compile_args = ['-std=c++11']
                    )


setup (name = 'checkyrs',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'checkyrs',
       ext_modules = [checkyrsai])
```

As I said above, this works perfectly. From this point I can open my python (2.7) interpreter,

```
import checkyrsai
```

and off I go to play with my new toy.

When trying to build for Python 3 I use almost exactly the same process, just with the addition of Python 3 flags for SWIG and running distutils through Python 3:

```
swig -c++ -python -py3 checkyrsai.i
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

this runs through the compilation successfully and produces the extension, but when I try to

```
import checkyrsai
```

I get the ImportError […] Symbol not found issue quoted above.

I don't change my code or the setup.py script in any way between the Python 2 and Python 3 versions. The symbol refers to a method which should be found in my libCheckyrs.dylib. It evidently is available there as it is used successfully when I use the Python 2.7 extension - but it seems not to be found when I make the extension for Python 3. Does anybody have any suggestion where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this issue by changing XCode project settings for the C++ library I was linking against.

Specifically, changing the "C++ Language Dialect" setting to "C++ [-std=c++11]", i.e. the same version I had specified in the extra_compile_args setting for distutils. Previously it had been GNU++11, hence symbols not matching as there was a mismatch in the namespace (std::vector vs. std::__1::vector).

With that change I'm now happily and successfully able to call my C++ code from Python 3.

I don't really understand why it *did* work in python 2.7, since it was using all the same distutils settings, with the same C++ version specified and the linking against the same C++ lib. If anybody has an explanation for that I'd love to hear it.